# Is there a subroutine that runs after the complete site has been loaded?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am using Page_Load to process a url in the form:

```
www.mywebpage.com?ids=1234&user=abcd
```

I think that Page_Load fires before the web page is fully loaded.

Is there a subroutine that runs after the complete site has been loaded?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ids1, user1
    ids1 = Request.QueryString("ids")
    user1 = Request.QueryString("user")
End Sub
```

Keep getting the error:

```
 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.117.222.18:25
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code

Comment: what about the end of `Page_Load` ?

Comment: The QueryStrings are an integral part of everything after.

Comment: Are you getting a bit confused about serverside & client side?  The Page_Load event will run on the server side as the page_loads.  The code you have shown will not cause the error shown, there must be more code elsewhere?  You can google for the asp.net page load lifecycle to see the full list of page events and the order in which they fire.  In general, page_load is the place you will want to do most of your work.

Comment: Dim client As New WebClient()Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead("http://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") + Request.ApplicationPath & "/PageDetails.aspx?ModuleID=" & ID)
Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Console.WriteLine(s)
data.Close()
reader.Close()

Answer (score 0):

I found this to give the Querystring more time to stop this error:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.117.222.18:25
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code

Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim data As Stream = client.OpenRead("http://" + Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST") + Request.ApplicationPath & "/PageDetails.aspx?ModuleID=" & ID)
Dim reader As New StreamReader(data)
Dim s As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
data.Close()
reader.Close()
```